# Is it possible to connect to OpenVPN on Windows, without a 3rd-party client?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, openvpn

The title says it all. Is it possible to connect to OpenVPN from Windows 7, without using a 3rd party VPN client? Can I use the native Windows VPN functionality alone?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The openvpn protocol is a custom protocol, not a standard like ISAKMP/IPSec, so no you need an openvpn capable client to connect and Windows does not have one built in.

Comment: This answer is a few years old. I was wondering if it's possible to install OpenVPN but still use the native Windows VPN "client". In Windows 10, there is a dropdown for "VPN Provider" but the only option is "Windows (built-in)". I was curious if I can use this without installing the plethora of different OpenVPN options, like the GUI.

Comment: @Zac from official openVpn docs you still need a third party client in windows 10 The. OpenVPN protocol is not one that is built into Windows. Therefore a client program is required that can handle capturing the traffic you wish to send through the OpenVPN tunnel, and encrypting it and passing it to the OpenVPN server. And of course, the reverse, to decrypt the return traffic. So a client program is required, and there are some options here https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/connecting-to-access-server-with-windows/